# Magento 2 Can you get Order Increment id from Invoice Increment id?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, increment-id

I am making a module where I am getting Invoice Increment id but I need Order Increment id. How to get the Order Increment Id by using Invoice Increment id?

If anyone has ideas please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$invoice = $invoiceModel->loadByIncrementId('000000011');// Your invoice increment id here
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Where **invoiceModel** is an instance of **\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice**

Comment: Yes,this is working.